# ASP.Menu Control's Click Event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have got a `ASP.NET` Menu Control that I bind to an `XmlDataSource` using `XPath`.
Now, menu structure is like,

- MenuItem1 - MenuSubItem1, MenuSubItem2, ...
- MenuItem2 - MenuSubItem1, MenuSubItem2, ...
- ... ... ...

It's strange but `Menu_MenuItemClick` event is being fired only for SubItems under menuItem1 but not for SubItems under other MenuItems.

Any Idea?

Comment: do u mean `MenuItemClick` by `Menu_Click` or what?

Comment: Yes, i do mean MenuItemClick event. Further, the page is being posted back all right and i can see the EventTarget/EventArgument Form items are correct.

Comment: check if you rebind your menu in post back

Comment: No, i don't. The ViewState is enabled for the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Check out code below it will help you to bind menu control using a xml file,

```
    private void CreateMenuWithXmlFile()
    {
       string path = @"C:\MyXmlFile.xml";
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ds.ReadXml(path);
       Menu menu = new Menu();
       menu.MenuItemClick += new MenuEventHandler(menu_MenuItemClick);

       for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
       {
        MenuItem parentItem = new MenuItem((string)ds.Tables[i].TableName);
        menu.Items.Add(parentItem);

        for (int c = 0; c < ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; c++)
        {
          MenuItem column = new MenuItem((string)ds.Tables[i].Columns[c].ColumnName);
          menu.Items.Add(column);

        for (int r = 0; r < ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count; r++)
        {
         MenuItem row = new MenuItem((string)ds.Tables[i].Rows[r][c].ToString());
          parentItem.ChildItems.Add(row);
        }
    }
   }

   Panel1.Controls.Add(menu);
   Panel1.DataBind();
 }
```